# JavaScript : trouble with If else if statement with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have 4 conditions; first three need to display error priority wise, the 4th one if all first three are false. I can't make it to work. How can I combine first 3 conditions in this statement?

```
if ((requireK3Action.length) || (requireAction.length) || (InvalidK3Action.length) ){

        if(InvalidK3Action.length){
            alert("Invalid condition 1");       
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;

        if (requireK3Action.length){
            alert("Invalid condition 2");       
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;

        if(requireAction.length){
            alert("Invalid condition 3");       
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;


        // all first 3 conditions satisfy
    } else if(!hasValidbehavior && noAction.length) {
        alert(" checking condition 4 ")
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You might want to review what putting statements inside `{ }` means.

Comment: Those return statements are outside of the `if` conditionals.

Comment: This should offer you a quick tutorial of *statement blocks* which you are using incorrectly, and is the reason you are getting inconsistent results.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: Thank y ou! It really helped!

Comment: You could have figured out this problem easily simply by stepping through your code with a debugger. If you don't know how to do this, then drop everything else you are doing right now and learn. By the way, in the future please provide more specifics than "I can't make it work".

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `return false;` from the first block before it is finished or add `return` into the three if statements.

```
if ((requireK3Action.length) || (requireAction.length) || (InvalidK3Action.length) ){

        if(InvalidK3Action.length){
            alert("Invalid condition 1");       
        }

        if (requireK3Action.length){
            alert("Invalid condition 2");       
        }

        if(requireAction.length){
            alert("Invalid condition 3");       
        }    

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;

}        // all first 3 conditions satisfy
else if(!hasValidbehavior && noAction.length) {

    alert(" checking condition 4 ");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you want to achieve, but try this:

```
if (InvalidK3Action.length) {
    alert("Invalid condition 1");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
} else if (requireK3Action.length) {
    alert("Invalid condition 2");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
} else if (requireAction.length) {
    alert("Invalid condition 3");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
} else {
    alert(" checking condition 4 ");
    //You can do the check here
    if (!hasValidbehavior && noAction.length) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

You may not need the first line:

```
if ((requireK3Action.length) || (requireAction.length) || (InvalidK3Action.length) )
```